# Actual text area not placing correctly with IE - how do I fix it?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

My website doesn't show right with IE whether I use the compatibility view or not. The text area of my site is either placed too much right or waaay too much down (starts right from where the last part of header image ends for some reason, I can't force the text go over the picture?).

I'd copy-paste the code parts I need help with if I actually knew where did I do wrong, but since I don't, I hope it's not too much to ask for to check out the whole site and its code.

http://viuhku.net/shaghas/skpr/skpr/

And CSS:
http://viuhku.net/shaghas/skpr/skpr/style.css

Comment: I mean the actual text, not <textarea>'s. Look at it with IE and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

Add `float: left;` in your CSS file under `#txt`

Comment: Well, that fixed the position of the text, but in IE it broke the background image's repeating.

Comment: @SuviLehto - add `display: inline-table;` to your `#bg` (sorry, it's hard to do it on IE without source code)

Comment: Damn, thanks! You're the best! :)
Now for the last question: Now that everything else works, do you have any idea why the position of the link is a little off with "SKY" - with this fix it seems to activate the hover-effect when you place the mouse a bit to the right from the actual link. It was correct before these two fixes you told me.
Happens with all browsers now.

Comment: @SuviLehto - `#txt` overlaps the item, you have to either shrink its width to about 750px, remove `padding-right` or set `z-index` of `#navi2` to like 9 or more. I'd recommend doing the third solution.

Comment: The third option worked, I set the z-index to 11 (playing it safe, haha). Huge thanks! You truly made my day, I was struggling with this - haven't coded anything for so long. :)

Comment: @SuviLehto - No problem. And welcome to SO! *As long as you remember to put code in your questions, and to accept answers and asking questions here will be a pleasure ;)*

Answer (score 0):

In your `#txt` class, you have a `padding-right: 200px` attribute; remove it and you should be fine.